# InputAccessoryView for Android?

Tags: react-native

For those of you using the InputAccessoryView component on iOS what are you doing for Android since it only works on iOS?

I've found these two libraries on github: https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-input.

Anything else out there to use or maybe some other approach I'm not thinking about?

Comment: I've used `react-native-keyboard-accessory` before and it works on android.